# NextJS use preventDefault on hashChangeStart event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJS with the next/router and I need to use the `event.preventDefault()` inside the `hashChangeStart` event but I don't see how can I do it because the handler only has the url as a parameter

This is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = url => {
      // here is where I need to use the event.preventDefault();
      ...
    };

    Router.events.on('hashChangeStart', handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      Router.events.off('hashChangeStart', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);
```

Any idea on how I can do it? I've also tried to use the `window.addEventListener("hashchange", myScript);` instead of the `Router.events.on` but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to call an event.preventDefault() when router run inside app?

Router event just return url or error follow event like **hashChangeStart**.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents

Comment: I'm doing a Router.push to the same url but changing the hash on another event and I want to prevent the jump to anchor link that I have with the same value